# Creating a communication channel between components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, events, ecmascript-6, rxjs

So I have two components, CompA and compA5 which are 3 or 4 levels apart, I want to create a communication channel between the components.

Lets say from component CompA i want to send event to compA5 to return some data, wait for it to return data and than take some action.
Is it possible to create a service or any other best practices to achieve this kind of behavior.

Comment: Yep, creating a service is the right approach, and potentially make use of `Observable`s as well if the action is a long running one

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for Component Communication where two components are either siblings or are not realted to each other is to create a shared service.

This shared service will have a `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` variable. Since this is a shared service, both the components will inject it as a dependency.

Now one can change the value of this `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` by calling `next` on it and passing it the data it wants the other component to get.

The other component will be `subscribe`-ing to this `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` and will get the data automatically.

Here's the [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sme3qd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a simple demo.

Comment: well i want to create communication channel, kind of like http.get().then(responseHandler()). The reason is i don't want to call a function on each property i change, i want to just handle that when i communicate with component

Comment: Ummmm... Sorry but I didn't quite get that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better than the original Angular.io documentation example [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).