# In Angular 5, how do you easily share a single instance of a Service for two instances of the same component type?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 5, how do you easily share a single instance of a Service for two instances of the same component type?

For example, suppose I have a NavMenuComponent which contains two instances of the NavMenuCartComponent as shown below within nav-menu.component.html

```
  <!-- Cart component instance 1-->
  <nav-menu-cart class="toolbar-item" *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"></nav-menu-cart>


 <!-- Cart component instance 2-->
  <nav-menu-cart class="toolbar-item" *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"></nav-menu-cart>
```

and each NavMenuCartComponent contains an instance of a cart as shown below

```
  navMenuCart: ICart = {
buyerId: '',
items: []};
```

When I update the navMenuCart in one instance, I want the other instance to also get that update as well. Is this accomplished with a shared service? Essentially I am trying to keep the state within each of the instances, ( in this case 2 instances of the NavMenuCartComponent ) in sync. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. A shared service would be the approach to go for here. Have a look at this answer: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992202/2622292

Comment: @Siddharth Ajmera, can you please provide some sample code to support this approach? upvote included.

Comment: Just did. Please have a look at it. This essentially is a case of Data sharing between two components. The service method is generally preferred in case there's no direct relationship between two components.

Comment: @Siddharth Ajmera, the reference you provided above is for two components of a Different Type. In my case above, it is two instances of the SAME component type, in my example above, NavMenuCartComponent

Comment: As long as the components are connected to the same module, they will always have the same instance of the service, given the service is provided in that module.

Comment: Looks like a good answer is to have a object on the service, and set the component object instance to that of the service, which will keep them in sync. I wish someone didn’t downvote me, sort of disincentivises me into contributing more to this post.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution I found was to actually create an instance of the interface within the service as shown below

```
    export class CartService  {
  cartUrl = environment.cartUrl;

  cart: ICart = {
    buyerId: '',
    items: []
  };
```

Creating a function within that service to return the INSTANCE

```
  getCart() {
return this.cart;
```

}

And then within any one of the components, set the instance of the cart to the instance of the service as shown below

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.navMenuCart = this.cartService.getCart();
```

}