# In ionic why label is not able to send value to another page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am stuck in a problem, in the code below I need to send chow Mein,22rs to another page using the button but it is not working. So is there any alternate method that can I follow to achieve this?

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>chow Mein</ion-label>
    <ion-label fixed>22rs</ion-label>
    <h3>hello</h3>
    <img src="assets/imgs/chillichicken.png" />
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to do this. One of them would again be to use a Shared Service.

This service would have a property. The page from where you want to send that data will set this property on the shared service. And the page where you want to get this property will get this property from the shared service.

Now it completely depends on what would be the property type be. Whether it would be primitive or complex.

Generally, it is recommended to keep this property as a `BehaviorSubject` to keep it more reactive. If you keep this property as a BehaviorSubject, then you can call the `next` method on it from the component that you want to send the changes to. And you'll be `subscribe`ing to this property on the page you want to listen for those changes.

Here's an **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992202/2622292)** I gave about it recently. You can also go through a sample StackBlitz project there.

Comment: is there any way we can do it for label in ionic

Comment: What exactly are you clicking? the `ion-item` itself?

Comment: in the code if i click the buttton the text values in the label must pass to another page thats all.

Comment: <ion-card>
<ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>chicken manchurian</ion-label>
<ion-label fixed>22</ion-label><ion-label fixed>rs</ion-label>
<h3>hello</h3>
</ion-item>

  <img src="assets/imgs/Manchurian.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
  </ion-card>
  </ion-list>

Comment: in the above code button is not present i have to include it later as per my logic my dout is to pass label values in ionic to another page

Comment: Consider creating a stackblitz demo. stackblitz.com/form/ionic

Comment: ion-item is a programming lanuage

Comment: I know what ionic is. It would just be more easy to demo what you're trying to achieve if there was a workable piece of code in place. That's why I'm suggesting you to create a stackblitz demo for the same:

https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic